# unreadable text in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application I am trying get xml from url and try to do some things. I have 2 language english and russian.

my xml looks like this

```
<root>
<dictionary>
<element name="english_text" lang="en">
Hello world
</element>
<element name="russian_text" lang="ru">
Привет мир
</element>
</dictionary>
</root>
```

When parse this xml try to show it, english is fine but russian not.

it is look like this.
[image]

What is the problem here. please help me

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Welcome to hell. Check that your editor uses the correct "UTF-8" i suppose, encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `UTF-8` encoding when you try to parse the document in your code, if you have not done that already.

If you are using httpClient for this purpose then it will look like this

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String results = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have to this in XMLParser class?

Comment: Yes wherever you try to parse the document

Comment: If I update my code try to add my xmlparser could you tell me more specific?